# Python, how to apply element wide AND operation on list without using numpy?

Tags: python

So I will to apply and element wise AND operation of each element between two lists of ints but only 0 and 1, and return a list. So I dont think `all()` is applicable here.
e.g.

[1, 0, 0] AND [1, 1, 0] => [1, 0, 0]

One way I can use list comprehension

`[i * j for i, j in zip(x, y)]`

But I wonder if there is a more bitwise way of doing it.

Many thanks.

Comment: `&` instead of `*`?

Comment: If you want a really complicated solution, convert each list into a number, combine the two numbers with `&`, then convert the result back into a list of binary digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `operator.and_` which essentially performs `bitwise and` operation, which is generally done by `&`:

```
>>> from operator import and_
>>> list(map(and_, [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0]))
[1, 0, 0]
```

Generally `list comprehension` should be preferred. As with `map` it is only useful when you have a builtin function, which in this case can obtained from `operator`, but even then, `map` approach has to perform another explicit `list` call, which would be slightly slower, furthermore even with builtin function list comprehension and map are almost identical in performance. Add that to the fact that list comprehension is generally more verbose. So unless you have a requirement to use functional approach, it is better to stick to `list comprehension`.

Comment: Thanks. That will do. Do you think it offers any advantage over list comprehension ? Sorry I am too lazy to timeit . :p

Comment: @J_yang https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map

Comment: @J_yang No, it does not.